# Show/Hide Section in dropdown menu for Gatsby Site

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

I am working on a Gatsby project.

I want to keep a folder of employees, each employee has it's own folder like `src/staff/hanna-rosenfeld/...` containing a `index.mdx` and a image file.

I want to source the staff's names and images to use in a component.

The goal is to build this:
[image]

my gatsby-config:

```
    module.exports = {
      siteMetadata: {
          title: "Musikschule Weimar",
      },
        plugins: [
        "gatsby-plugin-image",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
            name: `pages`,
            path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`,
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
            options: {
            name: `staff`,
            path: `${__dirname}/src/staff`,
            }
        },
        "gatsby-plugin-mdx",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
        "gatsby-transformer-remark",
        `gatsby-remark-images`,
        ],
    };
```

I already got the component that is doing the dropdown working:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { BiChevronDown } from "react-icons/bi";

import StaffList from "./StaffList"



const rows = [
    {
    id: 1,
    title: "Verantwortliche",
    },
    {
    id: 2,  
    title: "Lehrende der Zupfinstrumente",
    instrument: "zupfinstrumente"
    },
    {
    id: 3,  
    title: "Lehrende der Blechblasinstrumente",
    },
    {
    id: 4,  
    title: "Lehrende des Tasteninstruments",
    },
    {
    id: 5,  
    title: "Lehrende des Gesangs",
    },
    {
    id: 6,  
    title: "Lehrende des Schlagzeugs",
    },
    {
    id: 7,  
    title: "Lehrende des Akkordeons",
    },
    {
    id: 8,  
    title: "Lehrende der Musiktheorie",
    },
    {
    id: 9,  
    title: "Lehrende der Früherziehung",
    }
]


class DropDownRows extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
    }
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="dropdown-rows">
        {rows.map(row => (
        <div key={row.id}>
            <div className="row">
            <div className="col">{row.title}</div>
            <div className="col">
                <BiChevronDown
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                style={{float: "right"}}/>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
            </div>
            {this.state.isToggleOn ? <StaffList /> : ''}
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    )
    }
}

export default DropDownRows
```

src/staff/hanna-rosenfeld/index.mdx

```
---
title: Hanna Rosenfeld
featuredImage: ./Foto_05.jpg
---

Hi, mein Name ist Hanna und ich bin ein full time web developerin.
```

my StaffList component:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

    
function StaffList({ data }) {
    return(
    <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
        query staffQuery {
        allMdx {
            edges {
            node {
                id
                body
                frontmatter {
                title
                featuredImage {
                    childImageSharp {
                    fluid {
                        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }       
        `}

        render={data => (
        <div>
        <h1>{data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => <h1 key={edge.node.id} data={edge.node}>{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h1>)}</h1>
        <GatsbyImage alt='some alt text' image={getImage(data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage))} />
        </div>
    )}
    />
    )
}



export default StaffList
```

Querying for `featuredImage` works in graphiql, but i cannot get the image to show.
Console output:

> "Warning: Failed prop type: The prop image is marked as required in
> GatsbyImage, but its value is undefined."

The current state of the component on the site is this:
[image]

Getting the names to show up only in their category is another problem, for now I just want the images to show.

Thank you for any insight on a possible solution in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to comment on here:

The render structure is weird. You should do a loop through your data, as you are doing to display the `h1` but at the same time, you can take advantage of the loop to display the image of each employee.

In addition, you are using a Gatsby Image v2 GraphQL query structure (`gatsby-image`) while the render component (`GatsbyImage`) is from v3 (`gatsby-plugin-image`). I'd recommend reading the [migration guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/).

To summarize, when you query for `fluid` or `fixed` images as you do while using the ...`GatsbyImageSharpFluid` fragment you are querying a v2 structure and the render component should be `Img`(from [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/)), that is accepting a `fixed` or a `fluid` image. However, when you use a `GatsbyImage` component, the passed prop should be a `image` (no matter if it's fixed or fluid). So, you have conflicting plugins and structures. You should get rid of one of them and use the corresponding structure. To recap:

- `fixed` or `fluid` GraphQL query: v2 structure, the render component is `Img`
- `GatsbyImage` component: v3 structure. I will base my answer on that assuming that you will migrate to v3 (v2 is deprecated).

The issue rises up because as I said,`GatsbyImage` is expecting an `image` prop while you are passing a loop at and a wrong query data at:

```
<GatsbyImage alt='some alt text' image={getImage(data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage))} />
```

Use something simpler as:

```
   <div>
        {data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => (
         <article>
          <h1 key={edge.node.id}>{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h1>
          <GatsbyImage alt='some alt text' image={getImage(edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage)} />
         </article> 
        ))}
        </div>
```

When you end the migration, the full snippet should look like:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

    
function StaffList({ data }) {
    return(
    <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
        query staffQuery {
        allMdx {
            edges {
            node {
                id
                body
                frontmatter {
                title
                featuredImage {
                 childImageSharp {
                   gatsbyImageData(
                     width: 200
                     placeholder: BLURRED
                     formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
                   )
                 }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }       
        `}

        render={data => (
         <div>
        {data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => (
         <article>
          <h1 key={edge.node.id}>{edge.node.frontmatter.title}</h1>
          <GatsbyImage alt='some alt text' image={getImage(edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage)} />
         </article> 
        ))}
        </div>
    )}
    />
    )
}



export default StaffList
```

Check the opening/closing brackets and to clean the cache while changing the data sources by running `gatsby clean`.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked. Just also had to change it from  `<GatsbyImage alt='some alt text' image={getImage(edge.node.featuredImage)} />` to `<GatsbyImage alt='some alt text' image={getImage(edge.node.frontmatter.featuredImage)} />`.
Now the images are showing. Thank you again!!